# Google Tag Manager web or Apps - conditionally use Google Analytics Settings Variable

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am setting up GTM and wonder if I can use different Google Analytics Setting variable conditionally.
For example, if Page URL contains *staging* then use *GA Settings 1* variable, if not *GA Settings 2*

These two GA settings differs not only in Google Analytics Property ID but in a number of fields and custom dimensions. An alternative would be to duplicate tags which is not really what I would want to do...

Answer (score 2):

I just found this post whilst trying to achieve (I think) the same thing so for the benefit of searches here is my scenario and resolution.

My client's site is accessible via two domains (.com and .ie) each of which has their own GA property, but it is a single site connected to a single GTM container. I want to send data to the appropriate GA property based on the hostname.

In the GTM container I have created a lookup table variable which lists the hostname and the GA ID as appropriate, e.g.:

www.mysite.com | UA-123123-1

www.mysite.ie  | UA-234234-2

In my tag, I then can select this variable as my tracking ID. Importantly, I have to set the tag to allow overriding settings, which then allows me to set the tracking ID to this non-GAS variable type. If you just use the select box to select the GA variable then it will only allow you to select GA Settings variable types.

I have not yet tested this solution to set dimensions and fields but I would imagine you can you use a similar process.

Answer (score 1):

**No there is no option at the moment**:

- As you saw GA Settings variables don't allow you to do so
- [GTM environments](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6311518?hl=en) are meant for different purposes
- Using a Javascript variable returning GA Settings (see below) could work in theory but you're simply not allowed to select a variable that's not a GA Settings type from your tag, so no as well.

Workaround idea (point 3) that can't be used:

```
function() {
  if (    ) return {{GA Settings 1}};
  return {{GA Settings 2}};
}
```

So your options are:

- Separate tags
- Conditional custom HTML tag so you [set the fields yourself](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) with complete flexibility for each environment
- 1 tag with conditional variables: you set the fields/custom dimensions for both, except that the variables used return default values (for fields) or empty values (for custom dimensions) when they are not indeed in 1 environment.